# iOS Facebook SDK SSO Safari log out

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, single-sign-on

I use the latest `Facebook` SDK in my `iOS` app.

It uses single sign on, so even after calling `Facebook` logout method, when user log in again, dialog window saying he is already logged in fine.

In other `iOS` applications there is a logout button on Safari web view, so user can simply log out from app.

My question is how I can implement such `webView` in my application?

I know that I can use `FBDialog` instead of Safari window to control logout process but I need to have possibility to logout exactly from Safari web view. May be the window with logout button is accessible only in the old versions of SDK?

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing this problem,There is no default method to logout from facebook on safari when the app is under development,may be safari will show logout button when your app goes live on app store

Comment: I think that uploading app on app store will not change this strange behavior of Facebook SDK.

Comment: Facing the same problem. It's driving me crazy for a couple of days. Tried cleaning cookies, looked at Facebook source for keychain storage and UIpasteboard, but nothing works. I'm calling [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation] in my loggout - it wipes cached user credentials in NSUserDefaults. But even after deleting app and running it again it still remembers user login info and logs it automatically. Relogin only works after going to settings->safari and cleaning cookies and data. It seems safari somehow remembers login info but not in cookies...